# T-test in Compare of evolutionary Algorithms

Tags: matlab, hypothesis-test

I have implemented 2 evolutionary Algorithm. and run each of them for 100 trials.

I have saved the final best fitness values of each trial.

How can I use T-Test to compare final mean fitness of each algorithm with matlab?

I want to see whether a significant difference between Algorithm performance or not?

Comment: I hope there is nothing wrong with the normal distribution assumption in your data... depends on your algorithm ofcourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a set of 100 best fitness values for each algorithm you can use the `ttest2` function.

For example:

```
algo1 = your_results_for_algorithm1; %a 1x100 vector
algo2 = your_results_for_algorithm2; %a 1x100 vector

[h] = ttest2(algo1, algo2);
```

`h` will be true if the two algorithms have a significantly different level of performance with a significance level of p < 0.05.

Note: The `ttest2` function requires the stats toolbox.

Comment: do you can explain to me the retaurn values of ttest2()

Comment: i can not understand the output of this function

Comment: how can i send and email for you?

Comment: Read the `ttest2` documentation by typing `doc ttest2` in the command window of matlab. Also read [students t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) on wikipedia. If you have a lecturer/professor/teacher available, try asking them. And finally: no, you may not email me.